# How to match and merge two dataframes having completely different values except a single word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a dataframe ABC of value

```
        0                        1           2
0   sun is rising         |  UNKNOWN    | 1465465
1   micheal has arrived   |   UNKNOWN   | 324654
2   goal has been scored | UNKNOWN     | 547854
```

and other XYZ of value

```
    0         1 
0 sun       | password1
1 goal      | password2
2 micheal   | password3
```

how to map XYZ with (sun,goal and micheal) ABC and so that  1 with password would replace UNKNOWN 1 in ABC

output i need

```
    0                        1           2
0  sun is rising         |  password1    | 1465465
1   micheal has arrived  |   password3   | 324654
2   goal has been scored| password2     | 547854
```

Comment: So you only want to replace on column 1, so the actual password?

Comment: Have edited. want password1 on sun in sun is rising   ABC 1

Comment: please attach expected output too.

Comment: yes. Edited @NisheetPatel

Comment: To clarify are the rows supposed to be mapped simply by their order? Or is it necessary to search for matches among all possible rows? As my solution assumes

Comment: No not by order. ABC has    0  sun is rising    and XYZ has 0 sun     so using sun value we have to map

Comment: Yes, I mean by order of rows. So putting it in another way, should the result be the same if the order of the rows in XYZ was different?

Comment: have edited Please check @yatu

Comment: Yes, this is what I assumed in my solution. It should work fine using it

Comment: thanks. will work and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0],XYZ[1]))
#{'sun': 'password1', 'goal': 'password2', 'micheal': 'password3'}
pat = (r'({})'.format('|'.join(d.keys())))
ABC[1]=ABC[0].str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(d)
print(ABC)

          0                  1         2
0  sun is rising         password1  1465465
1  micheal has arrived  password3   324654
2  goal has been scored  password2   547854
```

Comment: @hukkemaaru - What is `print (ABC.columns)` and `print (XYZ.columns)` ?

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: print (ABC.columns) = Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

Comment: @hukkemaaru , your dataframe shows that you have a column 2 also, but it seems you just have 2 columns.

Comment: try `ABC[0].astype(str).str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(d)`

Comment: hi getting these error...            TypeError: sequence item 16069: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Hi, would appreciate if you can post  fresh question. SO doesn't advice iterative debugging :)

Comment: sure posting it

Comment: not matching properly. getting more mismatched values

Comment: @hukkemaaru and you cannot reproduce the issue as well. just for your information, this is a month old question. You could have easily posted a fresh question.

Comment: sure will do that.

Comment: @anky_91 please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902811/how-to-match-and-merge-two-dataframes-having-completely-different-values-except

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `str.contains` with `boolean indexation`  to select the password where a match is found between the two dataframes:

```
from itertools import chain
abc.loc[:,1] = list(chain(*[xyz.loc[abc[0].str.contains(i),1] for i in xyz[0]]))

         0                  1         2
0  sun is rising         password1  1465465
1  goal has been scored  password2   324654
2  micheal has arrived   password3   547854
```

Comment: got this error           NameError: name 'chain' is not defined

Comment: From itertools import chain

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: getting this error ..   IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Answer (score 2):

Create dictionary and match first value by `get` and `next`:

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ[0], XYZ[1]))
ABC[1] = [next(d.get(y) for y in x.split() if y in d) for x in ABC[0]]
print (ABC)
                      0          1        2
0         sun is rising  password1  1465465
1   micheal has arrived  password3   547854
2  goal has been scored  password2   324654
```

Comment: Have edited Please check. It is not mapped on order. it is by the values on XYZ 0 column

Comment: Change 0 to actual column name of your data frame

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: shall i post a new question about this ?

Comment: @hukkemaaru - Problem is in data I think. So need create question or modify data in this one which raise error... Because data in question working perfectly.

Comment: @jezrael please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902811/how-to-match-and-merge-two-dataframes-having-completely-different-values-except