# How to match and merge two dataframes having completely different values except numericals in columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, epoch

have a dataframe ABC of value

```
      id         |     price                          |   type
0     easdca     | Rs.1,599.00 was trasn by you       | unknown
1     vbbngy     | txn of INR 191.00 using            | unknown
2     awerfa     | Rs.190.78 credits was used by you  | unknown
3     zxcmo5     | DLR.2000 credits was used by you   | unknown
```

and other XYZ of value

```
         price          |   type
0      190.78           | food
1      191.00           | movie
2      2,000            | football
3      1,599.00         | basketball
```

how to map XYZ with  ABC ,so that type in ABC get updated with type in xyz using values(numericals) in price of XYZ .

output i need

```
       id         |     price                          |   type
0     easdca     | Rs.1,599.00 was trasn by you        | basketball
1     vbbngy     | txn of INR 191.00 using             | movie
2     awerfa     | Rs.190.78 credits was used by you   | food
3     zxcmo5     | DLR.2,000 credits was used by you| football
```

used this

```
d = dict(zip(XYZ['PRICE'],XYZ['TYPE']))

pat = (r'({})'.format('|'.join(d.keys())))

ABC['TYPE']=ABC['PRICE'].str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(d)
```

But values likes 190.78 and 191.00 are getting mismatched. 
for example while working with huge data 190.78 should be matched with food  values like 190.77 gets mismatched with food where it has other value assigned to it. And 198.78 also gets mismatched with some other ones where it should match with food

Comment: Super, so can you add solution with raised error with this data?

Comment: So it raise error?

Comment: 190.78 should be matched with food while using huge data value like 190.77 gets mismatched with food where it has other value assigned to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df

```
        id                price                                type
0       easdca        Rs.1,599.00 was trasn by you          unknown
1       vbbngy        txn of INR 191.00 using               unknown
2       awerfa        Rs.190.78 credits was used by you     unknown
3       zxcmo5        DLR.2000 credits was used by you      unknown
```

df2

```
           price                   type
0        190.78                    food
1        191.00                   movie
2        2,000                 football
3        1,599.00            basketball
```

using `re`

```
df['price_'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'(?<=[\.\s])[\d\.]+',x.replace(',',''))[0])
df2.columns = ['price_','type']
df2['price_'] = df2['price_'].str.repalce(',','')
```

Changing the types to float

```
df2['price_']  = df2['price_'].astype(float)
df['price_']  = df['price_'] .astype(float)
```

Using `pd.merge`

```
df = df.merge(df2, on='price_')
df.drop('type_x', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                id                                 price   price_       type_y
0      easdca        Rs.1,599.00 was trasn by you         1599.00   basketball
1      vbbngy        txn of INR 191.00 using               191.00        movie
2      awerfa        Rs.190.78 credits was used by you     190.78         food
3      zxcmo5        DLR.2000 credits was used by you        2000     football
```

Comment: working but  getting only two outputs not all. couldn't figure out why

Comment: hmm strange it works for me.. i'll advice to check the price columns

Comment: the problem is. in price column in df we have price_ with 1599.00 value but in df2 we have same value to be matched with 1599 and so inner merge is not working because of .00 it working fine for values with 2120.23 but not 1599

Comment: why dont you cast the price to floats..and then do merge

Comment: when i create the df, the type for price columns are str, now i am casting them to float.. see if this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
'''
First we make a artificial key column to be able to merge
We basically just substract the floating numbers from the string
And convert it to type float
'''

df1['price_key'] = df1['price'].str.replace(',', '').str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)').astype(float)

# After that we do a merge on price and price_key and drop the columns which we dont need
df_final = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='price_key', right_on='price', suffixes=['', '_2'])
df_final = df_final.drop(['type', 'price_key', 'price_2'], axis='columns')
```

**Output**

```
    id      price                               type_2
0   easdca  Rs.1,599.00 was trasn by you        basketball
1   vbbngy  txn of INR 191.00 using             movie
2   awerfa  Rs.190.78 credits was used by you   food
3   zxcmo5  DLR.2000.78 credits was used by you football
```

I assumed you made a typo in your `xyz` table, the third price should be `2000.78` and not `2000`.

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: Read the error, it literally says what the problem is.. You have convert your columns of both dataframes to float with: `df['Column'] = df.Column.astype(float).`  The column `price_key` is already float, so you have to change the `price` column of your `xyz` table to float as well.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Replace the commas in your string: `df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)`

Comment: Great move making `price_key` a float and using that for the merge, +1. Though, I would not rely on the precision on floats as keys for a merge for very _floaty_ values.